# An excitation of the gravity field

Tags: gravity, metric-tensor, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, perturbation-theory

Does the term "excitation of the gravity field" have any meaning ?(or is it just word salad perhaps?)
Other fields seem to have particles associated with them that are described  as an excitation in their particular field.

Does  this also apply to the gravity field?

Comment: [Graviton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton)

Answer (score 2):

In a context where the metric of spacetime is described by a slowly varying *background* (the simplest background is "flat spacetime," or no spacetime curvature), plus a small perturbation (which may describe a gravitational wave, for example), then sometimes one calls the small perturbation an "excitation of the gravitational field." In this context, one can make a strong mathematical analogy between the gravitational wave/perturbation and a wave in a classical field (such as the electromagnetic field) or even a quantum particle like a photon.

However, the picture of a background plus a small perturbation does not work in all situations. For example, when two black holes collide, the spacetime curvature is wildly varying in space and time near the collision. You might still say something like "the gravitational field is highly excited" to convey the idea that the metric is behaving in a very complicated way, but the connection classical wave propagation breaks down. The dynamics of the metric in this case are very complicated and non-linear.

---

In general relativity, the effects of gravity are encoded in the spacetime geometry, which is described by the *metric tensor* $g_{\mu\nu}$. The Einstein equations relate the curvature of the metric to the stress energy tensor of matter $T_{\mu\nu}$ as
$$
R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu} R = 8 \pi G T_{\mu\nu}
$$
in units where $c=1$. The left hand side involves the so called Ricci curvature $R_{\mu\nu}$ and Ricci scalar $R$; these are combinations of the metric and its first and second derivatives that describe the curvature of spacetime.

This is a set of ten second order differential equations for the metric, in terms of the source $T_{\mu\nu}$, which is the stress-energy tensor of all matter in the Universe. Therefore, like electromagnetism, the source term are a collection of functions (in the case of electromagnetism, these would be the charge density and current).

Now, as we said above, typically an excitation of the gravitational field actually arises when you write the metric as a background plus a perturbation, $g_{\mu\nu}=\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$. When using the language of gravitons, one is typically speaking about $h_{\mu\nu}$. Then, you can use perturbation theory to leading order to reduce the Einstein equations to a linear wave equation for $h_{\mu\nu}$, sourced by perturbations in the stress energy tensor.

Comment: Not sure if I am supposed to discuss further what Andrew has posted but I wonder what are the similarities and differences between the gravitational field and other fields such as ,for example the electron field?
Is the gravitational field viewed as having one "source" or infinitely many sources?Is there,perhaps one overall gravitational field which gets continuously modified as massive objects move wrt each other ?

Comment: @geordief I added a few paragraphs to address these questions.

Comment: Thanks very much indeed .That would be the first time I have been shown the EFE in fileted form:) Is the stress-energy tensor of the whole universe arrived at by setting  the boundary conditions I have often heard mentioned?

Comment: @geordief Einstein's equation are a set of differential equations, which are a machine that tell you how to update the current state "now" to the next state "a moment from now." In order to find a solution to this (or any) differential equation, you need to specify "boundary conditions" or "initial conditions" that tell this machine where to start. Exactly what kinds of conditions you need to specify depends on the form of the equations and is beyond the scope of a small comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot.That was probably as much as I could digest at this stage anyway.